# Bind html select to router param

Tags: ember.js

I have a dashboard which shows some stats for a cause/charity that can be chosen from a dropdown. When the user changes a new cause/charity from the dropdown I want to transition the router so that the name of the cause/charity is included in the url e.g. /#dashboard/British Heart Foundation.

Here's my attempt, the controller observes the currently selected cause/charity and transitions if it changes. The problem is the transition is triggered when the current cause/charity is set after loading the route which causes an infinite loop. Now I know I could check the previous value of the cause and make sure it's not null before triggering a transition but my approach feels a little bit off. What would be the idiomatic way of binding controls to router params?

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('dashboard', { path: '/dashboard/:cause' });
});

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return {
      cause: params.cause,
      causes: ['British Heart Foundation', 'Great Ormand Street Hospital']
    }
  }  
});

App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  changeCause : function(obj, keyName, value){
    this.get("target").transitionTo("dashboard", {cause: this.get("cause")});
  }.observes("cause")
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">
  {{ view Ember.Select contentBinding="controller.causes"  valueBinding="controller.cause" }}
  <h1>{{ controller.cause }}</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: It feels like you're trying to combine two different routes into one here: (1) The route /charities, which shows the dropdown but not a specific charity, and (2) The route /charity/ID that looks up a single charity by ID. There's a bunch of ways you could do this, using different names and/or nested routes. But it will all start making more sense as soon as try to split up these two cases, I think.

Comment: I'm only interested in showing the /charity/ID route, I'd never want to show the dropdown by itself. I always show /charity/ID with the dropdown at the top of the page - I've added a title to the template to give a better idea of what I'm going for.

Comment: Personally, I'd set up a /charities route and use `redirect` in the router to send it to the /charity/ID route you want to show by default, then. That way, whenever you're in the /charity/ID route, you'll always have a real ID. You definitely want to figure out the ID before getting there, or you're in for a really ugly fight with the router.

Comment: I'm just typing the name of the charity into the url for now, I agree that once I've overcome this issue it makes sense to have a route that redirects to a default cause. I'm really stuck on binding the select to the url param though, I've spent 4 hours on it now and got absolutely nowhere. It doesn't seem to be possible to get before/after values from observers.